# MCV3 Entity Framework 4 Code First: Adding Sub Objects to the db

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I am trying to teach my self MVC3 and EF4 using code first and the DbContext generator, so forgive me if this is a silly question.

Basically I have a user class, and an email class; this is because i want each user to be able to have multiple email addresses. the classes are set up like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]    
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }        
}
```

I am happily manipulating the user class using the CRUD methods build by MVC3 and inserting users programmatically to "seed" the db with test data, the latter i am doing like so by overriding the `Seed` method in the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` class like so:

```
public class dbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UserContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(UserContext context)
    {
        var Users = new List<User>
        {
            new User {  User_Name = "uname",
                        Password = "pword",
                        First_Name = "fname",
                        Last_Name = "sname",
            }
        };

        Users.ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));
    }
}
```

Now i would also like to add so email addresses, and because of the way i set up my classes code first obviously realises that each user can have multiple email addresses and each email addresses can belong only to one user because when creating a new user or email object the intellisense (VS10) presents me with `Emails` and `User` properties that are not actually part of either class.

My question is this: How do i add an email address to a user as its created, and how do i add an email address to a user that has been created previously?

Comment: Did you try adding `new Email`s? This is fairly trivial and well documented, to be honest.

Comment: I have been through several tutorials, and so far they all stop at adding an object like my user. I was just thinking that i need to add an ICollection of emails, but haven't had any luck with that yet. If its trivial and well documented, would you mind pointing me at the appropriate documentation? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add emails to user as it is created:

```
protected override void Seed(UserContext context)
{
    var Users = new List<User>
    {
        new User {  User_Name = "uname",
                    Password = "pword",
                    First_Name = "fname",
                    Last_Name = "sname",
                    Emails = new[]
                    {
                        new Email { Address = "email1@domain.tld" },
                        new Email { Address = "email2@domain.tld" },
                    }
        }
    };

    Users.ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));
}
```

To add an email to a previously created user, you first need a reference to the user:

```
var user = Users.First();
user.Emails.Add(new Email { Address = "email3@domain.tld" });
```

**Reply to comments:**

`new[]` is shorthand for `new Email[]` (new Email array).

Technically Eranga's answer is a little more flexible. In mine, since arrays are fixed length, you can't add an `Email` to the `Emails` collection after it has been initialized as an array. You would need to either use `List<Email>` as in Eranga's answer, or convert to a list like so before invoking `.Add()`:

```
user.Emails.ToList().Add(new Email { Address = "email3@domain.tld" });
```

I prefer arrays when possible because they are easier to type, less verbose in the code, and I generally add everything in the object initializer, so I don't need to add it again later.

That said, after you save the `User` and get it back out of the db, your `Emails` collection property will **not** be a fixed-length array, and can be added to without having to invoke `.ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks! what does the `new[]` do? I guess its shorthand for creating a list or something similar, but obviously googling [] doesn't achieve much

Comment: Cheers, both excellent answers, as a result I have learned alot. If i could accept two answers, or do some more up voting, i would.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Email to a new user

```
protected override void Seed(UserContext context)
{
    var Users = new List<User>
    {
        new User {  User_Name = "uname",
                    Password = "pword",
                    First_Name = "fname",
                    Last_Name = "sname",
                    Emails = new List<Email> { new Email { Addess = "foo@bar.baz" } }
        }
    };

    Users.ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));
}
```

Similarly for existing user.

```
user.Emails.Add(new Email { Addess = "foo@bar.baz" });
```

`user.Emails.Add` will issue a database request to load the Email collection (ie. Lazy Loading). Alternate way to do this is

```
var email = new Email { Addess = "foo@bar.baz", User = user };
context.Emails.Add(email);
```

Comment: Thanks! is there any draw back of using your method of adding addresses to an existing user when compared to danludwig's above where `user.Emails.Add()` is used instead? Obviously yours allows you to add more than one at once, but is it replacing the addresses that are already there?

Comment: @Ben I have edited my answer. Choose the approach depending on the situation.

Comment: Cheers, both excellent answers, as a result I have learned alot. If i could accept two answers, or do some more up voting, i would.